# Brouwer's fixed-point theorem and the intermediate value theorem?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

In one dimension, [Brouwer's fixed-point theorem (BPFT) can be proved easily based on the Intermediate Value Theorem (IVT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#One-dimensional_case). Is the inverse also true? I.e, is it possible to prove the IVT directly from the BFPT?

Comment: The link does not work. Pls. fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Let $f\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ be continuous, and assume, without loss of generality, that $f(a)<f(b)$. Let $t\in \mathbb R$ with $f(a)<t<f(b)$. Assume that $t$ is never attained by $f$.

Construct $g\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ by:

- $g(x)=a$ if $f(x)>t$;
- $g(x)=b$ if $f(x)<t$.

We don't have to define $g$ on points in which $f(x)=t$, since $f$ never equals $t$ in $[a,b]$.

Then $g$ is a continuous function whose image is contained in $[a,b]$. By the assumption on $t$,  $g(a)=b$, and $g(b)=a$, and $g(x)\ne x$ for all $x\in (a,b)$ (by construction of $g$). In other words, $g$ has no fixed-point, contradicting Brouwer's fixed-point theorem.

Comment: Why is this obvious that $g$ is continuous?

Comment: Because if $f(x)>t$, then $f(x+h)>t$ for sufficiently small $|h|$, by continuity of $f$.